# node sequelize: can I upsert object array at once?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nodes

object array like `[{id: 1, a: 1, b: 2}, {id: 2, a: 3, b:4}]`. and I hope to upsert the array to database using sequelize **upsert** at once. can it support array or should use loop to do it?

Comment: I see that the array contain id. It's mean that you only want update value. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `updateOnDuplicate` along with `bulkCreate` method as follows

```
model.bulkCreate(dataArray, { 
  updateOnDuplicate: [ 'a', 'b' ] // array of fields to update 
}).then(()=> {});
```

this is only supported by **mysql**

reference [bulkCreate](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

Comment: In document option updateOnDuplicate is Array. Pls update your answer

Comment: @ChuongTran thank you for noticing. I've updated the answer

Comment: Link to reference is wrong, bulkCreate: https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-bulkCreate